# Load google web app to a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-app-engine

Using google script I wrote a simple web app that returns a user email, deployed it and it works fine - returns active user's email.
The problem is that I to show that user's email on html page, something like:

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#userID').load('---web app url---');
});
```

HTML:

```
<p>Active user:</p>
<div id="userID"></div>
```

And I get error meggase:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load /web app url here/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The problem is in enabling CORS, as I understand, but I can't find a solution to it. 
How do I load that google web app to my html page?

I do not have a server, it's a simple html-page and I'm sure there must be a simple solution to this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really clear what you're trying to do, but to enable CORS you can do this on server, example in python using webapp

> self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

If you do not have the server, whose server are you trying to access?

Comment: google's. I wrote a google apps script (it's on my google drive) and deployed it as web app. now I need to include that web app as a part of my another web page.